# Mozilla Thunderbird - Multiple Addresses for 1 Individual

Tags: email, thunderbird

I use Mozilla Thunderbird as my default Email client. In my address books I have a few entries of individuals with multiple email addresses. I now address emails to each of their addresses as a separate entry when sending an email. How can I enter more than 1 address in my Thunderbird address book, so that when I enter that individual in the address field of an email all three addresses appear as a single entry? Can this be done? I would sincerely be grateful for any help that any of you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Mailing List](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-create-and-use-mailing-lists-thunderbird) for recipients with multiple email addresses.

[image: Thunderbird - Create Mailing List]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to show the *Address **B**ook* dialog.
- Right-click on the preferred location for the entry -- *Personal Address Book* or *Collected Address Book*.
- Select *New List*.
- Add each address for that individual -- Thunderbird helps auto-complete the entry if the individual address exists.
- Give the list a unique, easily-remembered name.

Now, when you add that single address to a To:, Bcc: or Cc: line, all the addresses in the list are included.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a contact, there is a space for "Additional email" - simply enter a comma separated list.  When you compose a message and type their name, you can pick to send either to just the primary email in the "Email" field, or all of the "Additional Email" entries.

(just tested on Linux Mint 19x Thunderbird 60.6.1)

[image: screen shot of multiple addresses on contact card]